# How to show that the square function is increasing i.e. $\forall x \geq 0; f(X)=x^{2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I read that this means to show $\forall x \in R x > y \implies x^{2}>y^{2}$. Whether it can be shown by $f'(x) >0$ or $f'(x) \geq0$?. Because, if its the first one then f^{'}(x) =2x = 0 at x=0 and hence square function would not be increasing. please clarify on that.

Comment: If you want to show it is strictly increasing for $x \ge 0$, it is sufficient to show $f'(x) > 0$ for $x > 0$. The fact that $f'(0)=0$ doesn't matter.

Comment: Actually, that $f'(0)=0$ means $f$ is not increasing at $x=0$ but since $f'(x)>0$ for all $x>0$ you know that $f$ is increasing everywhere in the right neighborhood of $0$

Comment: Also $x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y)$ so that $x^2>y^2$ if and only if $x-y>0$ assuming both $x$ and $y$ are nonnegative.

Answer (score 1):

We can show that $f(x)=x^2$ is strictly increasing as $\frac{d}{dx}x^2=2x$. Obviously, if $a>b$ and $a,b>0$, $2(a)>2(b)$, meaning that the derivative is strictly increasing $\forall{x}>0$. This proves that $f(x)$ is strictly increasing for $x>0$.